# Create filter/search function on multiple tables with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I've been able to follow the following tutorial that allows me to create a filter on 1 table.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

I would like to be able to filter multiple tables for the same input.

So:

- 1 input form
- multiple  definitions
- same filter on all tables
- show/hide on all tables if match

Would this be possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with a [mcve] showing specific code with which you're having a problem. As it stands this question is too broad to be answered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you. Just add the attribute `data-table` to all tables. And iterate over them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.mytable th, .mytable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

.mytable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.mytable tr.header, .mytable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable" class="mytable" data-name="mytable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <br><br>
<table id="myTable2" class="mytable" data-name="mytable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i,alltables;
    alltables = document.querySelectorAll("table[data-name=mytable]");
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  alltables.forEach(function(table){
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much! you are the best!

Comment: So, thank you for your awesome work.

Would it also be possible to hide the tables which are not filled after a search?